# Loop through each DB to pull Send As Permissions

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to pull Send As permissions from an Exchange 2010 Server.

I keep encountering an error that The total data received from the remote client exceeded allowed maximum.  Allowed maximum is 524288000.

As a way to mitigate this, I was thinking about running the command in a foreach loop for each database.

My question is, how can I get this to work?  The script above does not work unfortunately.

```
$allmbxinyourorg = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited
Foreach ($mbx in $allmbxinyourorg) 
{
    Get-Mailbox -database $mbx | 
     Get-ADPermission | 
       ?{($_.ExtendedRights -like     "*send-as*") -and -not ($_.User -like "nt authorityself")} |
         Select Identity, User | 
           export-csv -notypeinformation $mbx.csv
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an exch server to test this but you can try the following:

```
$databases = Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $yourserver

$databases | 
 Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited  
   Get-ADPermission | 
     Where-Object{($_.ExtendedRights -like '*send-as*') -and (-not ($_.User -like 'nt authorityself'))} | 
        Select-Object Identity, User | 
          export-csv -Path 'c:\temp\mbx.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

In your post you had the `export-csv` inside the `foreach` which would overwrite the file on every run of the loop.

Comment: I ran it but why was the foreach loop not included?  Also, I ran it and the output appear in the powershell screen but it did not output any of it to the path.

Comment: foreach loop is not needed when cmdlets accept values either by `valuefrompipeline` or `valuefrompipelinebypropertyname`...anyway if the result shows on screen it can be piped to `export-csv` ...do you actually have a temp folder on your system?

Comment: Yeah, I also tried changing my export-csv to go on to my desktop.   It definitely scrolls through a list of users but no output..

Comment: Nevermind, there was an output but it pulled all the permissions :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$allmbxinyourorg = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited
Foreach ($mbx in $allmbxinyourorg) 
{
    Get-Mailbox -database $mbx | 
     Get-ADPermission | 
       ?{($_.ExtendedRights -like "*send-as*") -and -not ($_.User -like "nt authorityself")} |
         Select Identity, User | 
           export-csv -notypeinformation 'mbx.csv' -Append
}
```

Could you post exact error you get? 
When do you hit the exception?

*$allmbxinyourorg = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited* or at another step?